# What are some options for charting time series stored in a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, statistics, graphite, grafana

I have a postgres database with a large number of time series metrics

Various operators are interested in different information and I want to provide an interface where they can chart the data, make comparisons and optionally export data as a csv.

The two solutions I have come across so far are, [graphite](https://github.com/graphite-project) and [grafana](http://grafana.org/), but both these solutions tie you down to storage engines and none support postgres.

What I am looking for is an interface similar to grafana, but which allows me to hook up any backend I want.  Are there any tools out there, similar to grafana, which allow you to hook up any backend you want (or even just postgres).

Note that the data I am collecting is highly sensitive, and is required by other areas of the application and so is not suitable for storing in graphite.

The other alternative I see would be to setup a trigger on the postgres DB to feed data into graphite as it arrives, but again, not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to replace Graphite's storage backend with postgresql. [Here](http://obfuscurity.com/2013/12/Migrating-Graphite-from-SQLite-to-PostgreSQL) is a good primer.

Answer (score 0):

**2018 update**: Grafana now supports PostgreSQL ([link](https://grafana.com/plugins/postgres)).

---

> What I am looking for is an interface similar to grafana, but which allows me to hook up any backend I want

Thats possible with grafana . Check this [guide](http://docs.grafana.org/plugins/developing/datasources/) which shows how to create a datasource plugin for a datasource thats currently not supported.